# Best practices when customizing PostgreSQL configuration files

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I am customizing my configuration files, both `pg_hba.conf` to allow LAN clients to access the DB on the machine and `postgresql.conf` to tweak my DB engine.

By now I am just editing the files I've seen in guides, so in `/etc/postgresql/{version}/main/pg_hba.conf`, its default location.

I noticed in the same root folder is also present a `conf.d` folder: what can I put in this folder?

How can I be sure to save my customizations when postgresql updates?
I would be more inclined towards making something like `my_pg_hba.conf` and put it into the `conf.d` folder: will this work? How can I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work, as long as the main `pg_hba.conf` contains a line like

```
include_dir conf.d
```

PostgreSQL will never overwrite or modify `pg_hba.conf` if you install new software. It is up to you to copy that file to the new cluster when you perform a major upgrade, along with all included files.